# Some Properties in PagePropertyList is not set in Eplan API while setting PageMacros

Tags: c#, plc

I have this code to set the `pageProperties` using Eplan Software API. I am little confused because some properties are set and other are not set. Like `DESIGNATION_FUNCTIONALASSIGNMENT` this is set but `DESIGNATION_PLACEOFINSTALLATION` this is not set. I read the documentation in which it is said that if the properties is of type `NamePart` it has to be set using `SetName`. I checked all of this properties are `nameParts`. So, what is the problem?

```
    PageMacro pageMacro = new PageMacro();
    string fileName = generatablePageMacro.Filename;
    pageMacro.Open(fileName, project);
    foreach (var page in pageMacro.Pages)
    {
        // Rename
        pageCount++;
        PagePropertyList pagePropertyList = new PagePropertyList();
        pagePropertyList = page.NameParts;
        if (generatablePageMacro.LocationIdentifier != null)
        {                           

            pagePropertyList[EplApi.DataModel.Properties.Page.DESIGNATION_FUNCTIONALASSIGNMENT] =
               generatablePageMacro.LocationIdentifier.FunctionAssignment;
            pagePropertyList[EplApi.DataModel.Properties.Page.DESIGNATION_PLANT] =
               generatablePageMacro.LocationIdentifier.Plant;
            pagePropertyList[EplApi.DataModel.Properties.Page.DESIGNATION_PLACEOFINSTALLATION] =
               generatablePageMacro.LocationIdentifier.PlaceOfInstallation;
            pagePropertyList[EplApi.DataModel.Properties.Page.DESIGNATION_LOCATION] =
               generatablePageMacro.LocationIdentifier.Location;
            pagePropertyList[EplApi.DataModel.Properties.Page.DESIGNATION_USERDEFINED] =
               generatablePageMacro.LocationIdentifier.UserDefinied;
        }
        pagePropertyList[EplApi.DataModel.Properties.Page.PAGE_COUNTER] = pageCount;
        page.SetName(pagePropertyList);   
        
        page.NameParts = pagePropertyList;
}
```